# MongoDB: connection already opened error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database, nosql

I'm unsure if I'm calling the database, mongo, efficiently. Right now I, open the db, get the collection, do my query, close the connection.

I', having a problem with mongo sporadically throwing: `connection already opened`

EDIT: All I'm doing is logging in and out a few times quickly and this error gets thrown, crashing the server.

What would cause this issue?

Thanks very much for any help!

(I'm using the node-native driver)

Comment: depends.if you want to make multiple requests within the same page,close the connection right before the page ended

Comment: The standard practice with most databases is to use a connection pool.  The pool will automatically open additional concurrent connections as needed to meet demand, and will typically start closing each opened connection after it has been sitting idle for some amount of time.  This would be more efficient than opening and closing a new connection for each request.  I'm not sure exactly how this would be done with mongodb and node.js, however.

Comment: It seems like I should just open it once...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How often should you open and close the database? Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374118/mongodb-how-often-should-you-open-and-close-the-database-why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since node.js is asynchronous, you can't be certain that your code will execute completely in one go.

It could be that during an asynchronous operation (as all the db ops are), node.js is handling another request, which will open up a new connection even though you already have one open.

What you should do is open up a single connection for the entire app. It is too inefficient to connect to the database at every page request, and as you have experienced, it can also cause problems if you don't implement it properly.