# MongoDB: How often should you open and close the database? Why?

Tags: mongodb, node.js

For every request I was opening the database, querying, closing the database.

I was sporadically running into a `connection already opened` issue.

I ended up changing the configuration  to just open mongo and keep it open.

What are the downsides to this method?

Thanks!

(note: using node.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looks as if you should open the connection once and keep reusing it, at least with the node-native-driver. Comments on the subject by the driver's developer found here: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues/84

Answer (score 2):

The answer here will depend on the version you're running. The method described on the [main github page](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native) involves opening/closing a connection "as required".

There is currently work on correctly supporting replica sets and providing some basic connection pooling. In fact, there was a check-in just yesterday to address [clean up of pooled connections on error](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/commit/c527e60fb217c152e543aa0542bfb1019acd8178).

Given that the docs provide this open/close method, this is probably the way to go. It's what I'm currently doing in my apps. As to the issue you're seeing, this may actually just be a bug. Again, the version on the driver is < 1.0 and there was a check-in just yesterday for something similar to what you're experiencing, so there may be some issues.

**Edit**: I should add that Christian is a great guy doing this work on his own time with limited support from the 10gen team. Building such a driver is lots and lots of work, so if you are encountering errors like re-using open connections, definitely file a bug and / or contribute a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the node.js driver, but the Java driver was designed to be used in this way: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Driver+Concurrency - it handles connections internally. Maybe the node.js driver does too. Perhaps it's worth emailing the driver's developers to ask?

Comment: Java driver and node.js drivers behave very differently. Java driver has a built-in configurable connection pool. The node.js driver is moving in that direction, but node.js is definitely different.